# administrator restrictions and no desktop icons

Tags: windows, permissions

my pc was running normally an hour ago, when i restarted it because i installed something, after the welcome screen, there are no desktop icons already and the programs in the start menu are also limited, and i cant ctrl+alt+delete and i cant even right clicked on my desktop, when i hover into my hard drive to start my avast, it says that "this operation has been cancelled due to restrictions on this computer" and to know that i am the administrator of the pc, what is happening?every application i click it says the same pop up message, please help,

Comment: I have the same problem, one Windows XP Home, some rogue antivirus program took administrator rights from the account, but I don't know how to fix it, as gpedit.msc is not available. I can't even get to the task manager.

Comment: this one took my icons, and my admin rights, damn

Comment: You're screwed up.

Comment: really really screwed up..

Answer (score 1):

The application that you have installed made something bad to your registry or maybe it was infected or just not intended to use on your version of Windows.

I think automatic registry repair tools wouldn't work in this case.

- Try to boot from anti-virus live CD and scan system disc.
- Try to boot in "'Safe' Mode" if it works than try Andrej's solution and also try to run in command line (to restore Windows protected files):

  sfc /scannow
- Try to use Windows System Restore, I believe it can help.
- Try to run gpedit.msc (not avialable in Windows XP Home) and fix your permissions.

Comment: so how do i fix this?

Comment: yes,the registry fix wont start anyway, still there are restrictions, any possible fixes?

Comment: any fixes available? i dont have any live AV virus cd..nor windows xp cd..

Comment: just tried the suggested fixes
-boot in safe mode= same problem
-boot in safe mode with cmd= hangs in process and mouse is disabled
-sys restore= there is no sys restore, still error

oh my God, im really toast..

Comment: How would it be possible to fix those problems without the group policy editor? There IS another admin account on the computer that is not affected, but I want the original one back.

Answer (score 1):

I think the one of the limited options you have is to boot in the safe mode and try to repair registry with appropriate tool like [this one](http://download.cnet.com/Free-Window-Registry-Repair/3000-2086_4-10606555.html).

Comment: its the same in the safe mode, limited icons and still there are restrictions..im toast..

Comment: Did you try to boot to 'last successful configuration'?

Comment: yes..but still just the same